# Accessing dynamically created row in jquery function

Tags: jquery

I have table that contains some select drop downs. Initially the table contains only one select drop down named 'item_code'. There is button named 'Add More' which will add  more select button in that table with same named 'item_code'. I want display an alert message using jquery function on the onchange event of the select drop down... My problem is I am able to access the static select drop down in jquery function, but unable to access the dynamic select drop downs. Jquery function is given below-

```
$(function () {
            var theValue;
            $('select').focus(function () {
                theValue = $(this).val();
            });
            $('select[name="item_code"]').change(function () {
                alert(theValue);
            });
        })
```

and my html code is given below-

```
<div style="height:240px; overflow:auto">
    <table id="dataTable" name="dataTable" border="1" bgColor="#9999CC" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <td>Item Name</td>
            <td>
                <select name="item_code">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <center>
                <INPUT type="button" id="add_items" value="Add Items" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" />
                <INPUT type="button" id="delete_items" value="Delete Items" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
        </center>    
</div>
```

and the javascript function for adding and deleting  rows are given below

```
function addRow(tableID) {

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            if (typeof  addRow.s_no == 'undefined') {
                addRow.s_no = 2;
            }
            else {
                addRow.s_no++;
            }
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {

                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

                newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;

                switch (newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                    case "text":

                        if (i == 1) {
                            newcell.childNodes[0].id = "s_no" + (rowCount - 1);
                            newcell.childNodes[0].value = addRow.s_no;
                        } else{
                            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";

                        }
                        break;
                    case "checkbox":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                        break;
                    case "select-one":
                        // alert("i......"+i);
                        if(i == 3){
                            //newcell.childNodes[0].name = "item_code";
                            newcell.childNodes[0].id = "item_code" + addRow.s_no;
                            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                        }else
                        {
                            newcell.childNodes[0].id = "item_category_code" + addRow.s_no;
                            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                }

            }
        }

        function deleteRow(tableID) {
            try {
                var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
                var rowCount = table.rows.length;

                for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                    var row = table.rows[i];
                    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                    if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                        if (rowCount <= 2) {
                            alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                            break;
                        }
                        table.deleteRow(i);

                        rowCount--;
                        i--;
                    }


                }
                var count = 1;
                for (var row = 0; row < addRow.s_no; row++)
                {
                    // alert(addRow.s_no);
                    //  document.getElementById(id).id="s_no"+row;
                    var id = "s_no" + row;
                    if (document.getElementById(id) != null) {
                        document.getElementById(id).value = count;
                        //  alert("count=="+count);
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                addRow.s_no = count - 1;
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
```

Can anybody give a solution for this problem

Answer (score 1):

Since the select drop down named `item_code` is added dynamically, you need to use [`event delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler like:-

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$('#tableID').on('change', 'select[name="item_code"]', function() {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

where, `tableID` is the ID of the static parent table, where select drop down is added using the `Add More` button.

Comment: @user2998739: Seems working here in th [`Fiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/sbN3H/)

Comment: Is any congiguration needed to support higher version of jquey?

Comment: Nothing like that, just need to include the higher version jQuery file.

Comment: I've edited my question. Can u kindly tell me why its not working?

Comment: Try to put all your jQuery code inside the [`$( document ).ready( handler )`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) method. The handler passed to **.ready()** is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code.

Comment: Still Not working.Now I am writing like that------$(document).ready(function () {

            // Attach Event
            // new way (jQuery 1.7+) - on(events, selector, handler);
            $('#dataTable').on('change', 'select[name="item_code"]', function () {
                alert(this.value);
            });
        });

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('body').on('change','select[name="item_code"]',function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

`.on()` attaches an event handler to the element.